# How would HDMI help me if the PC is not used to watch movies or play games?

Tags: hdmi

If I don't watch movies or play games, but the PC may be used to do some web-designing (not animations though), would HDMI help at all? Currently PC is using VGA.

It's more of a theory/hypothetical question, so please don't reply like "HDMI doesn't cost much" or "it's going to be outdated soon" or "this is better alternative to HDMI".

Comment: You may be interested in reading this question [comparing the different types of display connectors](http://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-vs-component-vs-vga-vs-dvi-vs-displayport/252864#252864).

Comment: Pretty much covers the same ground as http://superuser.com/questions/217960/advantage-of-connecting-laptop-to-monitor-through-hdmi-to-vga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI=DVI in quality, but DVI does NOT carry audio

Answer (score 5):

HDMI (and DVI-D) are digtial interfaces. They will, potentially give you a clearer picture on LCD monitors. VGA is analog, and often LCDs will render a less-than-crisp image even at their native resolution.

HDMI also has a DRM specification which *may* (depending on video hardware licensing) allow you to watch dvds which you might not be able to view over DVI or vga.

Answer (score 0):

The connector is smaller.  This enables smaller form factors and I prefer not having cables that need to be screwed in sometimes.